# How to get the first integers of a string without knowing the length in PHP

Tags: php

How can I extract the first part of a String (only integers) without knowing the exact length?

Examples

```
123456 - supplier returns 123456
12345 - supplier returns 12345
1234 - supplier returns 1234
```

Comment: regexp `/^(\d+?)\b/i`

Comment: If there are no numbers with spaces in them you could explode by space or use a regex to select only the first part of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[intval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)** is very powerful!

```
echo intval('123456 - supplier');  //123456
```

This explanation will help you understand why this works fine

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero). Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an 'e' or 'E' followed by one or more digits.

[**String Conversion to Numbers**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)

Comment: Beautiful solution! :)  *though you should leave the 'returns 123456' that was just to show what part I needed from the String.

Comment: By the way, it even works when there is white-space at the start of the string. Not between the numbers though...

Comment: @Bart that //123456 is not from question. It is there for people who will jump to say no this wont work. So its there to show them right that that it does

Comment: @HankyPanky no I mean '123456 - supplier returns 123456' should be '123456 - supplier'.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$full=explode(' ', '123456 - supplier');
$first=$full[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by many ways on of them is

> 1. REGULAR EXPRESSION

```
<?php

        $string = '123456 - supplier';
        $pat= '/(\d)*/';

        preg_match_all ($pat, $string, $pat_array);

        $digit  =  $pat_array[0][0];

        echo $digit;
      ?>
```

> 2.BY ARRAY EXPLODE

```
<?php
    $string = explode(' ', '123456 - supplier');
    $digit  = $string[0];
 echo $digit;
?>
```

> 3. INTVAL FUNCTION

```
<?php
$string = '123456 - supplier';

$digit = intval($string);  
echo $digit;
?>
```

Comment: What solution would you recommend? intval seems to be the cleanest but I'm not sure if there are cases where it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Bart Preg_match will always work. The other solutions depend on integer first, then chars.

Comment: I would suggest preg_match_all()

Answer (score 0):

```
Preg_match("/(\d+).*/",$string, $number);
Echo $number[1] //returns numbers of string
Echo $number[0] //returns the full string "12345 - supplier"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$testString = "123456 - blablabla";

function extractNumericsFromBeginning($str)
{
    $chars = str_split($str);
    $returnString = '';

    foreach ($chars as $char)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($char))
        {
            break;
        }

        $returnString .= $char;
    }

    return $returnString;
}

print(extractNumericsFromBeginning($testString));

// Output: 123456
```